# Change taskbar to allow double click to start programs?

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, double-click

I would like to be able to double click on programs on my taskbar to start them rather than one left click because I find myself accidentally starting programs when trying to quickly navigate to another program on the taskbar. Are there any windows tweaks that can do this?

Comment: Can someone tell me why I got downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps as I stated someone thought this was a silly/frivolous request.

Comment: @Karan I've personally seen at work about 20~30% of people doubleclick on programs they only need to single click on. This will be why it's included as a tweak in the program you listed. Zachrip is to be commended for learning that they normally should be single clicking in that location. It sounds like they've tried to break the habbit, but habbits are hard to break. Most of the staff I've instructed to single click on the programs in the start menu and/or pinned to the taskbar continue to fail to learn where to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any registry edit that would enable such functionality (probably because not many people would be interested in something like this), but it's a cinch if you use [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) as an installed or portable app:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 11, you can use Windhawk script:

Open pinned items with double click (pinned-items-double-click) by @m417z:

- https://windhawk.net/mods/pinned-items-double-click

Download Windhawk here:

- https://github.com/ramensoftware/windhawk/releases